# Wordpress multiple meta query

Tags: php, wordpress, post-meta

I am trying to get data from below query.  I want *result between two dates by first key and other key value if equal 1* but query returns value for me only today's date data and in sql add *OR* relationship. Please  help me to figure out the wrong and to get correction.

**My code is**

```
 $curent_date = date('Y-m-d');
 $start_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime($curent_date."- 4 day"));
 $end_date = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($curent_date."+ 4 day"));
$events_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => array('tribe_events'),
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
        'key' => '_EventStartDate',
        'value' => array( $start_date, $end_date ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'agenda',
        'value' => 1,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    ),) );
 print_r($events_query->request);

 print_r($events_query->posts);
```

**Return SQL is**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_posts.*, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value) as EventStartDate, MIN(tribe_event_end_date.meta_value) as EventEndDate FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as tribe_event_end_date ON ( wp_posts.ID = tribe_event_end_date.post_id AND tribe_event_end_date.meta_key = '_EventEndDate' )  WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' 
  AND 
  ( 
    mt1.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' 
    AND 
    ( mt2.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' AND mt2.meta_value BETWEEN '2017-05-22 00:00:01' AND '2017-05-30 23:59:59' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt3.meta_key = 'agenda' AND mt3.meta_value = '1' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'tribe_events' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND **(wp_postmeta.meta_value >= '2017-05-26 02:58:14' OR (wp_postmeta.meta_value <= '2017-05-26 02:58:14' AND tribe_event_end_date.meta_value >= '2017-05-26 02:58:14' )) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY EventStartDate DESC, wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

Compare datetime in wp_query you need convert your meta query item of date to `DATE Or`DATETIME`.

```
$events_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => array('tribe_events'),
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
'order'     => 'DESC',
'meta_query' => array( 
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
    'key' => '_EventStartDate',
    'value' => array( $start_date, $end_date ),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type'=>'DATE'
),
array(
    'key' => 'agenda',
    'value' => 1,
    'compare' => '='
),
),) );
```

and if this not working you can try this code

```
$events_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => array('tribe_events'),
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
'order'     => 'DESC',
'meta_query' => array( 
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
           'key' => '_EventStartDate',
           'value' => $start_date,
           'compare' => '<=',
           'type' => 'DATE'
       ),
array(
           'key' => '_EventEndDate',
           'value' => $end_date,
           'compare' => '>=',
           'type' => 'DATE'
       )
array(
    'key' => 'agenda',
    'value' => 1,
    'compare' => '='
),
),) );
```

Comment: No. Both are not working. Please look at my sql and there is the main problem. Bold text are return wrong result. Only todays result.

Comment: Your code in my server
http://downpublic.info/wpdemo/RS1991_ElseVillano/

Comment: but for me add this **OR (wp_postmeta.meta_value <= '2017-05-26 05:30:23' AND tribe_event_end_date.meta_value >= '2017-05-26 05:30:23' )) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY EventStartDate DESC, wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 10**